# Can radiosignals from Bluetooth-wristband have any impact on people health?

Tags: radioactivity

I don't afraid of low power radiosignals, but I need strong evidences to change minde of some people.
Not so long ago such devices has become popular and wide-spreaded. 
Is there any research about bluetooth-signals impacted in long-term period on healts?